# Ajax Request Return HTML Page

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am trying to send data from an Input to the controller of my application in Laravel, where I supply the category ID and it returns a jSON with the related id's.

I have a input to get data

```
<label for="categoryMae">Nome da Categoria Mãe</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="getCategoryMae" name="getCategoryMae" />
```

A `script` to pass to my controller

```
<script>
$("#getCategoryMae").blur(function(){
  var cat_id = $(this).val();
  console.log(cat_id);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '{{route('getCategoryName')}}',
    data: 'cat_id',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data.cat_id);
    }
  });

});
</script>
```

and I trying to get this values in my Controller (`Route::get('/categories/getCategoryName', 'CategoriesController@getCategoryName')->name('getCategoryName');`)

```
public function getCategoryName(Request $request)
    {
       $data = $request->all();
       dd($data);
    }
```

But the code returns the HTML structure and not the the value

[image]

How return only the value and not all that structure and why that happened? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to change `data: 'cat_id',` to `data: { cat_id: cat_id },` and check if it works...

Comment: Probably the HTML that is being returned contains the error, it would be nice to check its content.

Comment: Are you seriously returning data using dd function or is that just a provisional way of showing results?

Comment: @ggderas its just provisional.

Comment: @Laerte You're right, the error is in HTML, I put the same codes in a new application and it worked perfectly!

Comment: @ViniciusRosa Nice to know it! Great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're sending any data to your controller. Try this, check the data property of the AJAX call.

```
<script>
$("#getCategoryMae").blur(function(){
  var cat_id = $(this).val();
  console.log(cat_id);

  var dataObject = {cat_id: cat_id};
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '{{route('getCategoryName')}}',
    data: dataObject,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data.cat_id);
    }
  });

});
</script>
```

Also, I can tell you use Google Chrome, you can make sure you send something to the server, you can click on the **Headers**, go to the bottom to the **Query String Prameters** to see the parameters you're sending.
Here's a good resource: [Chrome Dev Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference)